# SAPUI5 using custom functions in sap.ui.controller

Tags: function, router, sapui5

I'm try to access the router inside a function that is called by another function, and the error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navTo' of undefined
sap.ui.controller.loginSuccess
request.onreadystatechange
```

I created a JSON model to connect in my server to authenticate the user, when I have a successful authentication, I call the loginSuccess from my controller.

Inside the controller I try to get the router to navigate in my pages.

```
login:function(){
    var login = new Login();

    login.loginAuth(
            this.byId("user").getValue(), 
            this.byId("passwd").getValue(), 
            this.loginSuccess, this.loginError );

    this.clear();

},

loginSuccess: function(type){
    var router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    if(type == "TIPO 1")
        router.navTo("MainPage", false);
    if(type == "TIPO 2")
        router.navTo("SupportMainPage", false);
    if(type == "TIPO 3")
        router.navTo("ManagerMainPage", false);
},
```

Why can't I access the methods of my controller inside this function?
I tried to access the this.getView() and doesn't work too.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: try calling `console.log(this);` at the beginning of loginSuccess. when that is not the controller you will have to call the function in the right context.

Comment: Herrlock, thanks for reply. How can I do this?

Comment: use loginSuccess.call(controller); (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` pointer is not pointing to your controller anymore. I guess it is either pointing to your `Login()` instance or `window`. To come around this issue you have several options:

```
login:function(){
    var login = new Login();
    login.loginAuth(
            this.byId("user").getValue(), 
            this.byId("passwd").getValue(), 
            $.proxy(this.loginSuccess, this), this.loginError );

    this.clear();
},
```

The $.proxy function makes sure that `this` points to the second parameter i.e. your controller. Another frequently used pattern is to add a parameter to your `loginAuth` function which is a `this` scope and call it like:

```
login.loginAuth(
            this.byId("user").getValue(), 
            this.byId("passwd").getValue(), 
            this.loginSuccess, this.loginError, this);
```

Your `loginAuth` function internally calls the given callback like this:

```
loginSuccess.call(scope, type);
```